# CreateProcess creating process, but game is not working

Tags: c++, process, game-engine

I have problem with `createProcess` function. The process is created, but game  is not working, game is not in the Applications tab. There are no errors. My code:

```
if(!CreateProcessA("D:\\GTASA\\GTASA\\gta_sa.exe", GetCommandLineA(), NULL,
    NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf( "Could not create process. (%ld)", GetLastError() );
        return 0;
    }

    // tutaj mozna sie wczepic w gta
    ResumeThread ( pi.hThread );
    // tutaj juz nie
    if(!pi.hThread){
    outputToConsole("Gra nie uruchomila się poprawnie.");
    }
    outputToConsole("Gra zostala uruchomiona!");

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    outputToConsole("Proces gry zostal wylaczony.");
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the game in it's own directory like so:

```
  string strDir = game_path.substr(0, game_path.find_last_of("/\\")); //Get the process dir name
      //STart the process in its dir
      if (!CreateProcess(game_path.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                         CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, strDir.c_str(), &siLoadee, &m_piLoadee))
```